# How to normalize data model / JSON in MongoDB?

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I am newbie on MongoDB JSON file developing. I am looking for the JSON file which contain another JSON file generation reference sites. Below is the my original JSON file.

```
[ {
    "Post" : {
        "id" : 1,
        "title" : "Title 1",
        "created_date" : "2018-12-01 11:10:13.247",
        "body" : " 국회는 헌법 또는 ....",
        "user" : {
            "username" : "joseph",
            "password" : "password"
        },
        "tags" : {
            "tag" : [
                {
                    "id" : 1,
                    "created_Date" : "2018-12-02 11:10:13.247",
                    "body" : "첫 글의 댓글입니다.",
                    "user" : {
                        "username" : "jina",
                        "password" : "password"
                    }
                },{
                    "id" : 2,
                    "created_Date" : "2018-12-03 11:10:13.247",
            "body" : "첫 글의 두번째 댓글입니다.",
            "user" : {
                        "username" : "julian",
                        "password" : "password"
                    } } ] } }   
}
,
{
    "post" : {
        "id" : 2,
        "title" : "Title 2",
        "created_date" : "2018-12-03 11:10:13.247",
        "body" : "제안된 헌법개정안은 대통령이 ....",
        "user" : {
            "username" : "joseph",
            "password" : "password"
        },
        "tags" : {
            "tag" : [
                {
                    "id" : 1,
                    "created_Date" : "2018-12-02 11:10:13.247",
                    "body" : "댓글 입니다.",
                    "user" : {
                        "username" : "julian",
                        "password" : "password"
                    } } ] } }   
}]
```

As you see, "user" and "tag" elements are repeated on every post documents. So I try to divide these elements into module-like files and can be referred to these elements on Post JSON file. But I have no idea how to divide these JSON data into another JSON files.

```
"user" : {
            "username" : "joseph",
            "password" : "password"
        }

[ {
    "Post" : {
        "id" : 1,
        "title" : "Title 1",
        "created_date" : "2018-12-01 11:10:13.247",
        "body" : " 국회는 헌법 또는 ....",
        "$ref" : user,
        "$ref" : tag
```

I hope "user" JSON elements be reused on "post" JSON.

Comment: What is a nested (JSON) file?   Perhaps you should reword this to use more conventional terminology, so that people can understand what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry for my poor English. I mean the json file containing another json.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense.  AFAIK, you can't put multiple JSON's into a single file ... in a way that a conventional JSON parser can read.  Perhaps you should give us an example of what you want the output to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is not a `JSON inside JSON` issue, its more about Data Modeling in mongoDB. You are using **Embedded Data Models** in your application and you need to follow **Normalized Data Models** using `references` to avoid duplication.

MongoDB have nice documentation on [designing the data models](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/#normalized-data-models) , have look.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to my understand, you want to separate repeatable parts from main collection(table). To achieve your idea you can be follow steps.

1. Create 2 different collections for keep details about main
   collection(table) and repeatable items.
2. Then you can be keep repeatable item collection reference on main collection.
3. When you required to read record use join to get whole details.

**More Info:** https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/